# how to deal with brng.toRad is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am using toRad() function in javascript as below

```
    var alpha1 = brng.toRad();
```

but when i run my code it gives an error saying "brng.toRad is not a function"

How does it work in java script, do i need to import some library???

Comment: What kind of object is `brng`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
Number.prototype.toRad = function () { return this * Math.PI / 180; }

var oneeighty = 180;
console.log( oneeighty.toRad() ); // 180 degrees = Pi radians
```

Answer (score 1):

Native javascript doesn't have a `toRad` function. Either

1) toRad was defined by google-maps somewhere and brng is just pointing to the wrong object (perhaps `null`?)

or

2) You need to define the method yourself

```
function toRad(degrees){
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

toRad(180);
```