# Find closest city to given longitude/latitude

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have a set of 10 citys and want to find out which one is the closest to a given longitude/latitude.

Any ideas how to do that using javascript?

thx. rttmax

Comment: I've no idea where to start...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this site](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), you can use the Haversine formula:

```
a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos(φ1).cos(φ2).sin²(Δλ/2)
c = 2.atan2(√a, √(1−a))
d = R.c
```

Which can be implemented in Javascript:

```
var R = 6371; // km
var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
var lat1 = lat1.toRad();
var lat2 = lat2.toRad();

var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d = R * c;
```

Then just do that for all of the cities using a loop and find the smallest.

Comment: Thank you very much! I needed to add: `Number.prototype.toRad = function () { return this * Math.PI / 180; }` as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889922/how-to-deal-with-brng-torad-is-not-a-function