# Sort an array based on value

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

What is the most effective way to sort an array based on a value. I have variable `user_location_lat` and a `user_location_long` togheter with the array `store_locations`.

My variable user location has (for example) this value: lat 45.222123123/long 54.5589858 the array look like this:

```
id: 4, lat: 43.22243243, longi: 52,342234
id: 5, lat: 45.22243243, longi: 65,432432
id: 8, lat: 77.22243243, longi: 77,555324

etc.
```

I know how I can sort an array based on the values inside the array. But not how I can sort them based on a value outside the array.

How can I find the nearest value from the array by `user_location`?

EDIT: And is it possible to get the closest location based on lat and long? See my edit above.

Comment: You need to first loop through the array of objects and calculate the distance to the `user_location` and add it as a property of the object. Then `sort()` the array by that property

Comment: How do you store the id related to the value in your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var latArray = [43.22243243, 45.22243243, 77.22243243]
var myLat = 45.222123123;

var closest = latArray.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
  return (Math.abs(curr - myLat) < Math.abs(prev - myLat) ? curr : prev);
});

console.log(closest);
```

source: [get closest number out of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584902/get-closest-number-out-of-array)

Comment: Thanks, but I've made a mistake in my code. I need to closest lat and long (see my post), is that possible? I thought lat only was enough in this situation.. but it isn't, sorry!

Comment: maybe check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594401/find-closest-city-to-given-longitude-latitude